# HTTP server from TCP socket (in Go)

Tags: linux, sockets, go, network-programming

I'm trying to create a TCP socket in Go, bind it into a [VRF interface](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/vrf.txt) and to establish a HTTP server in that specific interface. The VRF binding works correctly, but starting the HTTP server returns an error stating **"accept tcp 127.0.0.1:80: accept: invalid argument"**. Am I right to assume, that the socket is somehow defective and I'm creating it wrong?

Below is the simplified version reproducing the problem. VRF part is commented out as it doesn't affect the actual problem, but I'm leaving it here as I'm trying to avoid people telling me to just use net.Listen instead of sockets. VRF needs to be binded into first before it can be used so net.Listen isn't unfortunately an option.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "syscall"
)

func main() {
    fd, err := syscall.Socket(syscall.AF_INET, syscall.SOCK_STREAM, syscall.IPPROTO_TCP)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error creating socket: %v", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    // if err = syscall.SetsockoptString(fd, syscall.SOL_SOCKET, syscall.SO_BINDTODEVICE, "vrfiface"); err != nil {
    //  fmt.Printf("Error binding to vrf: %v", err)
    //  os.Exit(1)
    // }

    sockAddr := &syscall.SockaddrInet4{
        Port: 80,
        Addr: [4]byte{127, 0, 0, 1},
    }

    if err = syscall.Bind(fd, sockAddr); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error binding to IP and port: %v", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    file := os.NewFile(uintptr(fd), "socketfile")
    if file == nil {
        fmt.Println("Error creating file")
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    listener, err := net.FileListener(file)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error creating a listener: %v", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    http.HandleFunc("/", TestServer)
    if err = http.Serve(listener, nil); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error serving HTTP requests: %v", err)
    }
}

func TestServer(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Test, %s!", r.URL.Path[1:])
}
```

Any pointers on solving this would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What is wrong with existing web frameworks which could get you started in a minute?

Comment: normally, you need to `listen` to the incoming traffics.

Comment: Are you certain you need to bind to a specific interface? In Linux you rarely do that because the interface is chosen during routing. You should probably also just use [`net.ListenConfig`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/?tab=doc#ListenConfig) to control the connection setup

Comment: @JimB: The point of VRF is to have different routing tables per VRF device. One might even have the same IP address on different virtual devices on the same machine and the point is to explicitly bind to the interface which should be used and not let the OS pick some arbitrary one.

Comment: Thanks @SteffenUllrich. I assume then ListenConfig is probably the way to go to avoid the rest of the socket setup once you bind the device

Comment: @JimB: It would be nice if you could provide an actual example for this. As far as I can see the Control function in ListenConfig operates on the syscall.Rawconn and I can see no obvious way to get from this to the fd required by syscall.SetsockoptString.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: yeah, it is a bit abstract. I'll write up something in a min

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment by [C Han](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8233790/c-han) already: you need to listen.
The sequence of creating a server is to create the socket, bind to the IP and port, call **listen** and then accept incoming connections. If you forget to **listen** then you'll get the error you see. Thus:

```
if err = syscall.Bind(fd, sockAddr); err != nil {
     ...
}

if err = syscall.Listen(fd, 10); err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Error listening %v", err)
    os.Exit(1)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! My mistake was assuming that the listener would take care of this for me. Working perfectly now!

Comment: @AjMyyra: I nevertheless recommend that you use the [approach from JimB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60345282/3081018) instead since it simplifies the task and lets you use all the comfort of Go while still being able to bind to the device.

Comment: I did, actually. I marked your response as it was the clearest solution to the original problem, but JimB's approach is definitely a better way to handle this.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a [`net.ListenConfig`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/?tab=doc#ListenConfig) to inject the socket options you want before `syscall.Bind` is called. This also makes sure the socket setup is completed correctly, and in the same manner as expected by the `net` package.

The `ListenConfig.Control` function gives you a [`syscall.RawConn`](https://pkg.go.dev/syscall?tab=doc#RawConn) on which to call `Control` with a closure, where you have access to the raw file descriptor being using during the socket setup.

```
func main() {
    lc := net.ListenConfig{Control: controlOnConnSetup}

    ln, err := lc.Listen(context.Background(), "tcp", "127.0.0.1:80")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    ln.Close()
}

func controlOnConnSetup(network string, address string, c syscall.RawConn) error {
    var operr error
    fn := func(fd uintptr) {
        operr = syscall.SetsockoptString(int(fd), syscall.SOL_SOCKET, syscall.SO_BINDTODEVICE, "vrfiface")
    }
    if err := c.Control(fn); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if operr != nil {
        return operr
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: I've tried something like this too but got *"cannot use fd (type uintptr) as type int in argument to syscall.SetsockoptString"*. I also get this error with your code, i.e. does not compile for me.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: sorry, forgot the type conversion in there, I was testing on macOS, so using a different syscall. Should run now.

Comment: Thanks, and actually obvious in hindsight to just cast it to an int.

Comment: @JimB: Btw, is there a way to pass context to the control function? I'd love to pass the VRF interface name from there with context.WithValue or similarly.

Comment: @AjMyyra, there’s no context here, but you can generate a closure around whatever value need.