# With golang net/http, unable to close/shutdown http server if the server has explicit socket fd bind when created

Tags: go

I'm trying to implement a http server and I need to bind the underlying socket to a specific VRF instance so that the server only listens on that VRF instance. When some specific event happens, the program needs to shutdown the http server. I'm using syscall.SetsockoptString() and option "SO_BINDTODEVICE".

This is what I observe:

if there is no SetsockoptString() to bind the underlying socket fd call, the http server close call would succeed.

if there is a SetsockoptString() to bind the underlying socket fd call, then the http server close won't complete. In fact, it stuck in close() and won't return.

Seems in the path of close(), decref() does call fd.destroy(), and later on the program stuck in func poll_runtime_Semacquire.

comparing #1 and #2 in decref(), the state number for fd mu is different, so that fd.fdmu.decref() returns false and fd.destroy not getting called.

Here is my program:

```
func main() {
    // Generate a self-signed certificate and private key
    certPEM, keyPEM, err := generateSelfSignedCert()
    if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error generating certificate:", err)
    return
    }

    // Create a TCP listener
    listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", "localhost:443")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error creating listener:", err)
    return
    }

    //Get the underlying file descriptor
    file, err := listener.(*net.TCPListener).File()
    if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error getting file descriptor:", err)
    return
    }

    fd := int(file.Fd())

    //SetsockoptString to bind to a specific interface (replace "eth0" with your interface name)
    err = syscall.SetsockoptString(fd, syscall.SOL_SOCKET, syscall.SO_BINDTODEVICE, "")
    if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error setting socket option:", err)
    return
    }

    // Create an HTTP server with the custom listener and TLS config
    server := &http.Server{
    Addr:    "localhost:443",
    Handler: http.HandlerFunc(handler),
    TLSConfig: &tls.Config{
        Certificates: []tls.Certificate{{
        Certificate: [][]byte{certPEM},
        PrivateKey:  keyPEM,
        }},
    },
    }

    // Start the HTTP server
    go func() {
    fmt.Println("Starting HTTP server with TLS...")
    if err := server.ServeTLS(listener, "", ""); err != nil && err != http.ErrServerClosed {
        fmt.Println("Error starting server:", err)
    return
    }
    }()

    // Start a timer
    duration := 30 * time.Second
    fmt.Printf("Timer started. Server will be closed after %s.\n", duration)
    timer := time.NewTimer(duration)

    // Wait for the timer to expire
    <-timer.C

    // Close the HTTP server gracefully
    fmt.Println("Closing HTTP server...")
    if err := server.Close(); err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error closing server:", err)
    return
    }

    fmt.Println("HTTP server closed.")
}
```

The same goes for http server Shutdown(context) call. My question, does golang net/http packet support this scenario, shutdown() or close a http server where the server has some explicit underlying socket fd binding? If so, what code change should I make?

I was expecting server.Close() and server.Shutdown(...) to complete succesfully, independent of if the underlying socket fd has explicit syscall.SetsockoptString(....) when http server was created.

Comment: You're putting the socket into blocking mode, and not closing the associated file, which is not closed with the socket. Use the socket control function to make extra syscalls on the fd: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77754400/32880, or https://stackoverflow.com/a/60345282/32880

Comment: Thank you so much. Socket Control function solved my problem.